# How to change Google chrome windows order in the Windows task panel

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome

Usually I need much pages to be open at one time.
So there is a Windows task panel.
When I open multiple Google Chrome windows by Ctrl+N they appear in some order at the Windows task panel. Also in each windows I can create multiple tabs with pages (Ctrl+T).

I would like to create certain order of Google chrome Windows in the task panel. Say first is window with multiple tabs of my email accounts (gmail, yahoo mail etc). Second is window with tabs of google drive pages (different spreadsheets and docs files pages).

But sometime (I don't know why and how) the order changes itsef. Say window with emails tabs goes down... And then to create initial order I need to close all the windows and reopen them.

Could you please help with following:
1. Why order changes?
2. How can I change the order without closing and reopening all the windows?
3. If I create set of startup pages in the Google Chrome settings all of them open in the separate tabs but within one window. May I create a setting to open them in certain order of windows on each startup of Google Chrome?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use [7 Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker), which works on Windows 10 too.

[image]

The Grouping section under the middle pane has an option to "Drag within/between groups using right mouse button"

Comment: Awesome! Works well even on Windows 10 creators update! :)

Comment: This works great but unfortunately you need to do it every time you close/reopen the chrome :( Best thing would be to reorder it within chrome itself

Comment: This is driving me crazy! I work with large amounts of Windows, not able to reorder their positions is torture, god windows is so stupid... Did you find a solution within Chrome?!

Answer (score 7):

I usually do the close/reopen window trick to get the order right.

The steps are following:

1. I close a window I want it to go all on the right/bottom
2. I then click one of any other open remaining Chrome window to be sure that Chrome has the keyboard focus
3. I finally hit CTRL+SHIF+T (Windows) or COMMAND+SHIFT+T (MAC) to trigger the Chrome's command "reopen last closed window/tab". It will reopen the window I closed at (1.) and place it all the way to the right/bottom of the Chrome's window list.

Repeat it for several windows until you get the order you want, it takes a bit of practice to get the order right. One rule is to never close the window you want as leftmost/first.

Comment: This is too vehement for me! I have so many tabs quickly (even if I Am compartmentalizing them to separate windows) I can't even shift click them! And I open new windows a lot, this approach would take hours upon hours... I have usually like 20+ windows...

Comment: It's not my fault if Windows hasn't implemented a native way to do that, I only offered a workaround. Thank you for the kind downvote @empleat

Comment: It is not personal, shouldn't you downvote here based on whether or not solution works. Ye BTW microsoft 1 iq...

Comment: This is a better answer than using a third-party software to do this

Comment: +1 I would always prefer a simple workaround like this more than using some 3rd party for such small needs.

Answer (score 4):

For 1, this could be a few things, but I do not have enough information to work on.

For 2. Drag a tab out of the window. This will make this new tab the last window opened. Then shift click the left most and right most tab, and drag them into the new window. This will keep open all the tabs while moving the window to the last one.

For 3, I think you can only open one window without third party extensions. You can however have Chrome re-open from last session, which will let you restart Chrome exactly from where you left off.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is close all your windows in the order you want it from left to right. Then reopen all your windows by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

Comment: This may not work perfectly in all cases, i.e. if the pages to close have some dynamic content, but it's a surprisingly easy method that works fine in most cases. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate answer

Answer (score 0):

Go to fullscreen into Google Chrome pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> twice.

Then that Chrome window will go the bottom of the list.

[Reference](http://lifehacker.com/5562837/use-chromes-full-screen-toggle-to-organize-its-windows-thumbnails)

Comment: Sadly this no longer seems to work. (Chrome 50-ish and up.)

Answer (score 0):

An intuitive solution, using **Session Buddy**:

- Install the extension [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko?hl=fr)
- With this extension, export your session as text, and make sure to include in your export the windows, the titles, and the URLs.
- Reorder the windows as you like. (You don't need to change the windows numbers).
- Close all the windows. (You can do it quickly from within Session Buddy).
- Import you modified text.

Or you could also do it with **Simple Window Saver**:

- Install the extension [Simple Window Saver](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-window-saver/fpfmklldfnlcblofkhdeoohfppdoejdc)
- With this extension, save each one of your windows with a descriptive name.
  And each time, after you saved the window, close it.
- Once finished, reopen each of your windows in the order you want them from last to first.

That's it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

8 years later, and the order of Google Chrome windows still changes by itself sometimes... On Windows  10, I usually only need to bring the window I am currently using to the right of the group in the taskbar, and the easiest way I found is the following:

1. open a new empty tab in the window to move
2. select all the other tabs (select the first one, hold SHIFT then select the last one)
3. drag them somewhere else in the middle of your screen, Google Chrome will create a new window for them
4. close the old window with the empty tab
   Easier and shorter than creating a new window first them moving the tabs to it...

Answer (score -2):

Here is how to solve your problems (1) and (2).

You need to discover ***Chrome Task Manager***.

Press *Shift-Esc* or find it under *More Tools > Task Manager*.

For your needs, it has many benefits over Windows Task Manager:

- it shows only Chrome processes
- it shows the titles and favicons of all the open tabs
- it lists processes in the same order as the browser tabs
- the tabs for each browser window are grouped together

If you accidentally close your Yahoo Mail tab and you want it back where it was, you can do this:

1. In any Chrome browser window, open a new tab and log in to Yahoo.
2. Drag the Yahoo tab to your Chrome email window, and position it where you want it among the other email tabs.
3. Close Chrome Task Manager, then open it again. Voila! All your email tab tasks will show up grouped together, in the order you want them.

Answer (score -5):

Press ALT, then you can use mouse drag the window in task panel.